# CakePHP 3 Migrations Plugin Error when running bin/cake Migrations migrate

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I pretty much use Migrations every time I work with CakePHP and I never encounter any issues.

This time, however, I am having an issue trying to execute the following command

```
bin/cake Migrations migrate
```

I had created the file using

```
bin/cake bake migrations CreateTaxes state:string[5] ...
```

The file created successfully, but when I run the command to migrate, I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class Migrations\CakeAdapter contains 1 abstract method 
and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods 
(Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface::getVersionLog) in 
/var/www/taxes/website/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/CakeAdapter.php
on line 670
```

I cant figure out why it is throwing this error and not allowing the command to finalize. I have looked at both `CakeAdapter.php` and `AdapterInterface.php` for Phinx.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a bug that has now been fixed. https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/202

Comment: Thanks for reply, i had this problem too kk

Comment: You are welcome! It was strange... I am glad CakePHPMigrations developers quickly fixed it.